# Rspec request says it can't find the form field 'Account name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my rspec request I did:

puts page.html

and I can see:

```
<label for="account_account_name">Account name</label>
<input id="account_name" name="account[name]" size="30" type="text" />
```

My rspec request:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Account pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "new" do

    before { visit account_new_path }

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        #puts page.html
        fill_in "Account name",       with: "acme inc."
        fill_in "Company name",       with: "acme inc."
        ..

      end

      it "should create a account" do
        expect { click_button "Create Account"}.to change(Account, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Running:

```
rspec spec/requests/account_pages_spec.rb
```

I get the error:

```
1) Account pages new with valid information should create a account
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Account name",       with: "account name1"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Account name' found
     # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
     # ./spec/requests/account_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Why can't the element be found?**

Again did output the page.html in the before block and it did output the correct html that I pasted above.

Comment: The label's for attribute doesn't correctly identify the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label's `for` attribute doesn't correctly identify the input field.

Comment: yes I have account name also, I cut/pasted the wrong html. I updated the html thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
fill_in "account[name]", :with => "acme inc."
```